# How to have row_number() start again in 1, once a distinct value is encountered?

Tags: sqlite

I have the following table in SQLite where I query using

```
select plain_note_id, id from attachment order by plain_note_id, id;
```

Here's the result.

```
plain_note_id   id
==================
5               1
5               2
5               8
9               3
9               5
```

I wish to migrate to the following new table structure. Can you suggest me several SQLite statements able to do so?

```
plain_note_id   id  order
========================= 
5               1   1
5               2   2
5               8   3
9               3   1
9               5   2
```

I guess I need to use `row_number()`. But, I am not sure how. I tried

```
select 
    plain_note_id, 
    id, 
    row_number() over (ORDER BY plain_note_id) as `order` 
from attachment 
    order by plain_note_id, id;
```

I am getting (Not the result I want)

```
plain_note_id   id  order
========================= 
5               1   1
5               2   2
5               8   3
9               3   4
9               5   5
```

Does anyone has any idea how I can use `row_number()` properly in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In `row_number()` you will have to group by `plain_note_id` and order by `id` to get the desired output :

```
select 
    plain_note_id, 
    id, 
    row_number() over (PARTITION BY plain_note_id ORDER BY id) as `order` 
from attachment
```